# What does 'private (string, object)[] s;' mean/do?

Tags: c#, class, object

so i am fairly new to c# and i know about arrays and 2D-Arrays but this one is new for me and i have no idea what it does/ what it is used for.

```
class Testclass
{
   private (string, object)[] s;

   public Testclass((string, object)[] s)
   {
       this.s = s;
   }    
}
```

In this code theres the property `private (string, object)[] s;` and the constructor for the `Testclass` that uses this property.

But I don't understand what kind of array this is and what it contains.

I am thankful for any help. Thank you very much.

Comment: It's an array of Tuple types. Read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples

Comment: `(string, object)` is a `ValueTuple` struct, so `s` is an array of this type.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#tuples-and-discards

Comment: Thank you so much... ill read into that. Now i know what its called.